# Trying to implement Set ADT with LinkedListStack in java. When I try to remove a specific mapping

Tags: java

I am trying to implement Set ADT with LinkedListStack. When I try to remove a specific mapping, toString() method gives nothing.The result is:

Contents:

Blaz 124,   Anton 123,  Alen 122,  Lukac 121,  Martin 120

Size: 5

... running

What is wrong with remove() method? Can you fix it? thanks

```
    public class LLStackMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V>{

    private LLStack<KeyValuePair<K, V>> pairs;
    private int size;

    public LLStackMap(){
        pairs = new LLStack();
        size = 0;
    } 

    @Override
    public void define(K key, V value) {       
        KeyValuePair n = new KeyValuePair(key, value);
        pairs.push(n);
        size++;       
    }

    @Override
    public V getValue(K key) {
        LLStack <KeyValuePair<K, V>> s = new LLStack(); 
        int a = pairs.getSize(), b = s.getSize();     
        for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
            try {
                KeyValuePair x = pairs.pop();
                s.push(x);
                if(x.getKey() == key){
                    while(b>0){
                        pairs.push(s.pop());
                    }                    
                    return (V)x.getValue();
                }                
            }catch (Exception ex){}
        }                 
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(K key) {
        LinkedListQueue <KeyValuePair<K, V>> z = new LinkedListQueue();
        int a = pairs.getSize(), b = z.getSize();  
        KeyValuePair y = null;
        if( getValue(key) != null){           

              for(int i=0; a>0; i++){
                try{
                    y = pairs.pop();                
                    if(y.getKey() != key){
                        z.enqueue(y);                    
                    }else{
                        while(b>0){
                            pairs.push(z.dequeue());                                         
                        }
                        size--;
                    }                     
                }catch(Exception e){}    
               }
            return (V)y.getValue();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {       
        pairs.clear();
        size = 0;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String s = "";
        s = s + pairs.toString();        
        return s;
    }
   }
```

Here is the Test Class:

```
    public class LLStackMapTest {

       public static void main(String[] args){
        LLStackMap s = new LLStackMap();  

        s.define("Martin", 120);
        s.define("Lukac", 121);
        s.define("Alen", 122);
        s.define("Anton", 123);
        s.define("Blaz", 124);
        System.out.println("Contents:\n" + s);
        System.out.println("Size: " + s.getSize() + "\n");
//      
        System.out.println(s.getValue("Martin"));

//                      
        s.remove("Blaz");
        System.out.println("Contents:\n" + s);
        System.out.println("Size: " + s.getSize() + "\n");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; a>0; i++){
    ...
}
```

`a` never changes inside of this loop. It's an infinite loop.